# wasting 4th hour behind textblock wrap in accordion

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Why is this not working :-

```
<toolkit:Accordion x:Name="___No_Name_"  Margin="0"  SelectionMode="OneOrMore" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=grid}"
                       >
        <toolkit:AccordionItem Header="Welcome" Margin="10,0" IsSelected="True" >
             <TextBlock Margin="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="This site was created using FMT. This is a great system that allows anyone This site was created using FMT. This is a great system that allows anyone This site was created using FMT. This is a great system that allows anyone This site was created using FMT. This is a great system that allows anyone " FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="13.333" Foreground="#FF033C68"/>
        </toolkit:AccordionItem>
        <toolkit:AccordionItem Header="Family news" Margin="10,0" />
        <toolkit:AccordionItem Header="Random photos" Margin="10,0" />
        <toolkit:AccordionItem Header="News articles" Margin="10,0" />
    </toolkit:Accordion>
```

I can only see the 1st line. The rest of the content is clipped. Why is the height not automatically setting it up even though i have a wrap on textblock? Why is this control harassing me so much? What wrong am i doing? Why can't i get the normal expected behavior with this control?

Even this simplest possible markup doesn't work.

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit" x:Class="SilverlightApplication3.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

        <toolkit:Accordion HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0">
            <toolkit:AccordionItem  Header="Header">
                <TextBlock Text="This is a great system that allows anyone This site was created using FMT. This is a great system that allows anyone This site was created using FMT. This is a great system that allows anyone This is a great system that allows anyone This site was created using FMT. This is a great system that allows anyone This site was created using FMT. This is a great system that allows anyone This site was created using FMT. This is a This is a great system that allows anyone This site was created using FMT. This is a great system that allows anyone This site was created using FMT. This is a great system that allows anyone This is a great system that allows anyone This site was created using FMT. This is a great system that allows anyone This site was created using FMT. This is a great system that allows anyone This site was created using FMT. This is a This is a great system that allows anyone This site was created using FMT. This is a great system that allows anyone This site was created using FMT. This is a great system that allows anyone This is a great system that allows anyone This site was created using FMT. This is a great system that allows anyone This site was created using FMT. This is a great system that allows anyone This site was created using FMT. This is a " TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </toolkit:AccordionItem>
        </toolkit:Accordion>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I think i found the problem. Accordion is inside scrollviewer which is causing the problems. Not sure though.

Comment: No my doubt was wrong. Please read my edited post.

Comment: I have a similar issue where the I have <LineBreak/> elements within several paragraphs of text.  It appears that the height of the AccordionItem is set based on each paragraph being on one line, then the wrapping is applied expanding the height of the rendered text, however, the AccordionItem height is not expanded, and the text block is clipped at the height before wrapping.  I'm not sure what the cause is of this, yet, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text in a `TextBlock` won't wrap unless the `TextBlock` also has a `Width` set.

I took your 'simplest possible markup', added `Width=1000` to the `TextBlock` and the text wrapped as I expected it to.

Comment: - I did not want my textblock to have a explicit width set on it. I ended up dumping Accordion and put static Expanders which works fine in my case and i don't have to set any explicit width on any control. Thanks anyways :)